# reference functions to array slices in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is the following was possible in python?

(I am pretty new to python, not sure what the appropriate search term would be)

I have a class that stores and manipulates a large numpy array.
Now I would like to access parts of this array via an alias 'reference function'

Here is a dummy example for illustration

```
import numpy as np
class Trajectory(object):
   def __init__(self,M=np.random.random((4,4))):
      self.M=M

   def get_second_row(self):
      return self.M[1,:]

   def set_second_row(self,newData):
      self.M[1,:]=newData

t=Trajectory()
print t.M
initialData=t.get_second_row()
t.set_second_row(np.random.random(4))
print t.M
```

What I don't  like about this is that I have to write separate set and get functions. is there a simpler way to use just one function to refer to the parts of the array M that would work for both getting and setting values?

so speaking in dummy code, something that would allow me to do this:

```
values=t.nth_row
t.nth_row=values+1
```

I would like to use t.nth_row as a reference for both getting and setting the value if that makes sense

Comment: `def get_nth_row(self, n): self.M[n+1, :]` ?

Comment: On a side note, your get function is missing a `return`

Comment: @Hamms, I extended my example to specify more clearly that I want a function that can both get and set the a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a simpler way to use just one function to refer to the parts of the array M that would work for both getting and setting values?

Yes, and you've written it. It is your `get` function:

```
initialData=t.get_second_row()
t.get_second_row()[:] = np.random.random(4)
t.get_second_row()[0] = 1997
```

Comment: can you give me just a key word - what's the principle behind this?

Comment: pass-by-object-reference

Comment: array slicing is one principle.